# How do I sum a column range in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
df 

No Name     Address    English  History  Math   Physics  Chemistry  Biology
1  Arthur   New York        80       65   100        89         92       94
2  Barthur  New Mexico      70       60    94        83         82       95
```

What I did is

`df['Science'] = df['Math'] + df['Physics'] + df['Chemistry'] + df['Biology']`

My problem is, the actual data is more than 900 column, how do I replace `df['Math'] + df['Physics'] + df['Chemistry'] + df['Biology']` to sum from `df['Math']` to `df['Biology']` (by range)

I hope this question is clear enough

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions:

```
df['sum'] = df.iloc[:, 3:].sum(axis=1)
```

Or remove numeric columns which dont need:

```
df['sum'] = df.drop('No', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   No     Name     Address  English  History  Math  Physics  Chemistry  \
0   1   Arthur    New York       80       65   100       89         92   
1   2  Barthur  New Mexico       70       60    94       83         82   

   Biology  sum  
0       94  520  
1       95  484
```

EDIT:

If need only all columns from `5` to the end:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 5:])
   Math  Physics  Chemistry  Biology
0   100       89         92       94
1    94       83         82       95

print (df.iloc[:, 3:5])
   English  History
0       80       65
1       70       60

df['A'] = df.iloc[:, 3:5].sum(axis=1)
df['Science'] = df.iloc[:, 5:].sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   No     Name     Address  English  History  Math  Physics  Chemistry  \
0   1   Arthur    New York       80       65   100       89         92   
1   2  Barthur  New Mexico       70       60    94       83         82   

   Biology    A  Science  
0       94  145      520  
1       95  130      484
```

Comment: I also dont need English and History as well, I need `df['Science'] = df['Math'] + df['Physics'] + df['Chemistry'] + df['Biology']` . Please edit your answer

Comment: I edit answer. Is possible define all subject by groups?

Comment: You should `df['Science'] = df.iloc[:, 5:9].sum(axis=1)` instead, but you answer this question completely

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Yes, you are right. Thank you for accepting, nice day!